# Xcode Server: concurrent bot builds?

Tags: xcode-bots, xcode-server

Is there any way to get multiple bots building simultaneously? I cannot find any documentation about this (Xcode Server docs are pretty thin as is). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be possible at this time. The Xcode user _xcsbuildd is running in a fully interactive GUI so it can use the iOS Simulator for testing.

Even though you can launch multiple simulators at a time, Xcode can only attach to a single simulator for debugging - in turn, meaning Xcode Server can only test a single integration at a time.

Comment: I see. The way forward is probably just to work on getting individual targets to build faster, since XCode already knows how to parallelize compiler invocations. Thanks.

Comment: You can do it now. Xcode Server supports this by default.